# Solution to a state-space equation

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system

In my notes on non-linear linearization there is the following example. It asks to verify the solution to the state-space equation. My understanding is that the solution is where the equilibrium point is. In other words, where the vector x'(t) is equal to zero. Thus, I plugged in the solution into x'(t) and one can see that it is not zero. Specifically, for the theta'(t) term, it is equal to omega_0 which is clearly not zero. Or have I misunderstood these notes?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "My understanding is that the solution is where the equilibrium point is" Your understanding is not right. Just differentiate the given solution with respect to time and see if it satisfies the differential equation.

Comment: Hmmm, if x0(t) is a solution then differentiating it gives [0 0 t 0 0 0]^T which is not a solution. If you set the first elements equal you get 0 != r_dot(t)?

Comment: @Calculon although the next part says "Linearize the nonlinear state-space model space model
around the operating trajectories x around the operating trajectories x0(t) and u0(t)
given in (a). given in (a)."

So this leads me to believe that the solution is where the equilibrium is?